# Some doubts about Html.BeginForm work in .cshtml view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am pretty new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following doubt about how .NET handle forms in **.cshtml** file.

In a view named **Index.xshtml** I have something like it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Vulnerability", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
{

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="Filter_CVE">CVE:</label>
        <input type ="text" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true" id="Filter_CVE" name="Filter.CVE"  value="@Model.Filter.CVE"   />
    </div>   

    <div data-role="controlgrup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <input type="reset" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" value="Seach" data-icon="search" />
    </div>
}
```

Now it is pretty clear for me that this code create a form and 2 buttons. My doubt is related tho this line

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Vulnerability", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
```

Looking to the official documentation (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) I can't find my situation.

So what is the meanining of the previous **BeginForm** method parameters?

I think that they could be:

- **Index:** it represent the page name? (my view is named **Index.xshtml)
- **Vulnerability:** what represent?
- **FormMethod.Post:** I think that this specify that the form sending is POST
- **new { id = "MyForm" }:** what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Index**: this is the name of your action

**Vulnerability** is the name of your controller

**FormMethod.Post** means the form is sent via POST

**new { id = "MyForm" }** are the html attributes, in this case the `<form>` tag wil get an ID of MyForm

Imagine you have the following code in your `VulnerabilityController`:

```
public ActionResult Index() {

}
```

Your form will send all the data entered in the HTML input fields to the Index action (by POST)

Answer (score 3):

There's a [documentation for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Method signature :

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

- **actionName**

Type: System.String
The name of the action method.

- **controllerName**

Type: System.String
The name of the controller.

- **method**

Type: System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod
The HTTP method for processing the form, either GET or POST.

- **htmlAttributes**

Type: System.Object
An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.

Answer (score 1):

**Index**: This is your `View`, and will be represented in the controller as an *Action Method*

**Vulnerability**: This is your `controller`

**FormMethod.Post**: This sets the form [`Method`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

**new { id = "MyForm" }**: This will set the id of the form, as in `<form id="MyForm"`...